# "Cannot open database [db] requested by the login." when server is rebooted. Works fine after resaving web.config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2008

So, every time this issue occurs, I simply open the web.config for the site and save it. This instantly fixes this issue until the next server reboot. This works great, but I do not want to have to do this every time. I saw several posts about this that reference permissions, but that does not seem to be my issue (due to the way I can resolve it each time).

Anyone happen to have some insight as to why this action might be fixing it or any ideas as to what might be causing this issue?

Note: The site uses SQL Auth.

Comment: I would suggest using SQL Profiling on your SQL Server to see what [db] it is requesting when it fails.  That might provide a clue as to what's really going on.

Comment: That's a good idea. I am not super experienced with that tool, but I assume I would have to get the site back in the state with the issue to test in this way, correct? If so, I'm not sure how well that would work as it is a public facing site that needs to be up ASAP after a reboot. Are there perhaps logs somewhere that might store this data (sorry again for my inexperience with SQL Server).

Comment: Ask your DBA if the database has a default trace running.  (SQL Profiler is the UI to the Sql server trace facility)  These are on by default, but I don't know if they capture enough information to tell you what DB it was trying to connect to.  If not, you could have them run a very narrow/specific trace in the background for just this purpose.  Then when it happens, you can go back to it to check.  But all that might be a lot of work just to get this one piece of information ...

Comment: Is the sql server on the same machine as the web server?  If so, asp.net may be coming up before sql server is ready.  Check the sql ERRORLOG.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA They are running on the same machine. I will look into that log. I was thinking that might have been the case as well, but would re-saving the web.config (essentially restarting the site) resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, that's not really a solution though.  I would expect the asp.net application to throw some errors for a couple of minutes while sql comes up, then the errors should go away on their own.  How long do the errors occur for?

Comment: They stayed for at least 10 minutes once and between 5-20 minutes another time (not sure how quickly the outage was reported). Both times, it was only corrected when I saved the web.config (which I by chance noticed fixed it). I really did not have  a chance to diagnose the situation, since I had to get the site up ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

When you resave web.config your site restarts so you can solve it by restarting your web site in IIS manager as well. This problem is most certainly because your w3svc service starts before your sql server service. Set your w3svc service to delayed start and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolves when you set the webservice starttype with Delay and change the login to Administrator instead of local.